# Can you identify this species?

Tags: species-identification, zoology

[image]

It is similar to a kinkajou but it isn't for sure. I would include it into carnivora, and then maybe canifornia but I really don't have a clue.

Comment: With Chrome, if you have a picture, you can do a right click on it and do a google image search. Doing so with the image you provided finds, amongst others, the wikipedia page for the Common spotted cuscus

Comment: The fruit seems to be [*Averrhoa carambola*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Averrhoa_carambola), oxalidaceae.

Answer (score 10):

That's a marsupial, the spotted cuscus, [*Spilocuscus maculatus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_spotted_cuscus).

Here is another image:

[image]

By the way, the same individual in your photo can be found [in this site](http://www.ozanimals.com/Mammal/Spotted-Cuscus/Spilocuscus/maculatus.html) about Australian animals, still eating that starfruit:

[image]